# Can't connect to MySQL docker container created via docker-compose

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I want to get started with docker and created a simple container environment with an nginx container, a PHP-FPM container and a MySQL container.

While the link between the nginx and PHP-FPM container works well I can't seem to link the PHP application server with the database server.

I use docker-compose to minimize the manual terminal work. My docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```
web:
  image: tutorial/nginx
  ports:
    - "8080:80"
  volumes:
    - ./src:/var/www
    - ./src/vhost.conf:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/vhost.conf
  links:
    - php
php:
  image: nmcteam/php56
  volumes:
    - ./src/php-fpm.conf:/etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf
    - ./src:/var/www
  links:
    - db
db:
  image: sameersbn/mysql
  volumes:
   - /var/lib/mysql
  environment:
   - DB_NAME=demoDb
   - DB_USER=demoUser
   - DB_PASS=demoPass
```

While I try to connect to the DB with the following statement:

```
$db = new \PDO('mysql:host=db;dbname=demoName', 'demoUser', 'demoPass');
```

The MySQL container itself is working as I can connect to the containers bash and use the MySQL CLI:

```
mysql> show databases;

+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| demoDb             |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
+--------------------+
```

I just get a 500 error and can't find a reason why this wouldn't work. Any help or suggestion of what I might have missed is more than appreciated.

Comment: Your connection string should be `$db = new \PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=demoName', 'demoUser', 'demoPass');` if connecting locally otherwise you need to expose the port and use the ip of the host machine.  Linking only exposes the linked container internally to the application it is linked to.  You can't reference it by db, you must reference it by `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`

Comment: @GHETTO.CHiLD thanks for the effort. I commented on the answer you provided.

Comment: are you connecting from the nginx box?

Comment: @GHETTO.CHiLD I'm not sure if I get your question... As the PHP application server interprets all my PHP code it should connect through this container. Please correct me if I'm mistaken here.

Comment: can you run this command: `$db = new \PDO('mysql:host=db;port=3306;dbname=demoName', 'demoUser', 'demoPass');` and post the result

Comment: @GHETTO.CHiLD it's still just displaying the 500 error with your update. I tried to see if docker is logging some error using 
    `docker logs [dockerID]`
but there was nothing suspicios at all.

Comment: @GHETTO.CHiLD but to answer your question the last thing that is logged is `[30/May/2016:09:29:29 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 5 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36"` logged by the **nginx** container

Comment: Try this:  `$db = new \PDO('mysql:host=db;port=3306;dbname=demoDb', 'demoUser', 'demoPass');`  You have `DB_NAME=demoDb` but are setting `'mysql:host=db;dbname=demoName'`.  Change that, reconnect and see if it works. I don't think this is a Docker issue but a code issue.

Comment: @GHETTO.CHiLD oh my god..... you're right.... looking for difficult solutions is preventing to find easy answers. thank you... that fixed it. I just got totally blind here.

I still got some issue cuz i can't see the database docker-compose created but that's another issue. thanks for your time.

flagged the question as off topic

Comment: im going to correct my answer so you can set it as the proper one.  also, np.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a Docker issue but a code issue:

You have: `$db = new \PDO('mysql:host=db;dbname=demoName', 'demoUser', 'demoPass');`

It should be: `$db = new \PDO('mysql:host=db;port=3306;dbname=demoDb', 'demoUser', 'demoPass');`

Answer (score 1):

If you have `0.0.0.0` host for your container with MySql and you want to connect with the database from outside docker (WorkBench or SequelPro), just use your docker-machine IP. Example:

```
user$ docker-machine ls
NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                         SWARM   DOCKER    ERRORS
default   *        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.100:2376           v1.12.0
```

Then your host to MySQL is `192.168.99.100` with proper port e.g. `3306`

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to expose the database port to the host network, **by setting up your "db" service ports**:

```yaml
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:3306:3306
```

Now your mysql 3306 port will be visible from outside. Not having this setting, would make it available only to other services on the same network.

*Note: 127.0.0.1 is optional, it specifies that port 3306 is accessible only from localhost, and not from another ip, eg. someone connecting from outside*

Answer (score -2):

You are using `sameersbn/mysql` as base image for MySQL which exposes `EXPOSE 3306/tcp` according to this [dockerfile](https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-mysql/blob/master/Dockerfile).

I think you need expose port 3306 to 3306 in the container. you can do this by adding the following to your `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
db:
  image: sameersbn/mysql
  volumes:
   - /var/lib/mysql
  environment:
   - DB_NAME=demoDb
   - DB_USER=demoUser
   - DB_PASS=demoPass
  ports:
   - "3306:3306"
```

I personally would use the original [MySQL](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/) image instead of the one you are using.

However, as a full solution of what you are trying to achieve `(Nginx, PHP-FPM and MySQL)` consider using [LaraDock](https://github.com/LaraDock/laradock) this open source project is designed for Laravel but you can easily modify it to make it work with your PHP code.

Comment: - "3306:3306" <-- what you're doing in here is opening mysql port to the whole world..

Comment: This actually makes you MySQL server open to the internet. Bad for security.